# Pandoc: HTML to Markdown - remove all attributes except IDs

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Is there any option or extension in pandoc to remove all attributes except IDs when converting from HTML to markdown?

I want to remove attributes, like `.class-name`s, `style`, `aria-label`, `height` & `width`, and reserve IDs, so that bracketed spans contain only IDs.

The current output:

```
### Some Heading {#some-heading .some-heading aria-label="some-heading" style="text-align: center"}

![Some image]("path/to/image.png"){#some-image .some-image width="200" height="100"}
```

The desired output:

```
### Some Heading {#some-heading}

![Some image]("path/to/image.png"){#some-image}
```